# Does the camera need to be re calibrated again on restart / OPENCV

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, calibration

I have been doing camera calibration of my webcam using opencv (later to be used on mini cameras) and am wondering doing I need to run the camera calibration program every time I start up my camera? Is there a way to permanently set the calibrated values, also does the distortion coefficients depend on how the chessboard (used for calibration) position in front of the camera vary ?

Comment: The camera intrinsic parameters depend on the camera lens. There is no need to calibrate again if you do not change the camera lens.

Comment: @Catree - but I have noticed a slight change in the camera matrix values when I calibrated again, though rounding off is the same value. Hence for my clarification, calibrate the camera once, disconnect, and connect it to the apparatus that uses the camera for application purpose.

Comment: @Catree - but I have noticed a slight change in the camera matrix values when I calibrated again, though rounding off is the same value. Hence for my clarification, calibrate the camera once, disconnect, and connect it to the apparatus that uses the camera for application purpose.